# Android calculator with single edit text displaying complete input and output

Tags: android, calculator

I want to display the complete input and output of my app.

For example:

`2+2=4` needs to be displayed after clicking "=" in the calculator.

My problem is that app closes unexpectedly.

```
package com.scientific.calculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class Calculator extends Activity{

    EditText display;
    Button btn,btnop,add,sub,mul,div;
    ToggleButton shift;
    String operator,result;
    float value=0;
    Character op = 'q';

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator);
        display = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDisplay);
        shift = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tbShift);
    }

    public void set_number(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        btn = (Button)findViewById(v.getId());
        result = display.getText().toString();
        display.setText(result+btn.getText().toString());
    }

     public void btnplusclicked(View v){
           perform(v);
           op = '+';

          }

          public void btnminusclicked(View v){
           perform(v);
             op = '-';

          }
          public void btndivideclicked(View v){
           perform(v);
           op = '÷';

          }
          public void btnmulticlicked(View v){
           perform(v);
           op = '×';

          }

          public void btnequalClicked(View v){
              evaluate();

          }

          public void perform(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                btnop=(Button)findViewById(v.getId());
                result=display.getText().toString();
                operator=btnop.getText().toString();
                display.setText(result+operator);
               }
                  private void evaluate() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      value=Float.valueOf(display.getText().toString());
                if(op == '+')
                 value=Float.valueOf(display.getText().toString())+value;
                else if(op == '-')
                    value=Float.valueOf(display.getText().toString())-value;
                else if(op == '/')
                    value=Float.valueOf(display.getText().toString())/value;
                else if(op == '*')
                    value=Float.valueOf(display.getText().toString())*value;

                display.setText(String.valueOf(value));
               }


}
```

Comment: can you post the logcat please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand this way. When you click equal to `evaluate()` is called.

In which the first line is `value=Float.valueOf(display.getText().toString());`
That is converting what is the `display` to Float.
Though computer is able to convert the first digits but when it come and reads the operator in between. It can't convert that. Hence the crash. Just to be assured.

Type 2 and then press `equal` I bet it won't crash.

Now either you can do is. When ever a operator ( + - * / ) is called. Use a float variable and calculate it and keep it in the memory. Once the user presses Equal to. Display that Value. Simple as it is.

For more reference Have a look at [simple cal](http://theandroid.in/simple-calculator-in-android-source-code/) or [complex calc](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104931/Introduction-to-Android-development-TouchCalculato)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to parse `'123+25'` to float. so it will give error.
 And what if user presses `'1+2-3*4'` what would be your `operator '*'` . so it might not work properly. please check here for a good example on [calculator](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_BasicsUI.html) for android..